# Phonegap/Cordova and Couchbase Mobile/server

Tags: rest, cordova, mobile, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm creating my mobile app using phonegap.

I decided to use Couchbase to store datas; but I can't figure out if I must have to use Couchbase mobile or I can connect my app (javascript) directly with couchbase server, and how to 'query' my .net app.

I have downloaded the couchbase server on my system, but how to connect it with my app?

Can I use N1QL to 'query' the server with .NET also using phonegap? (because couchbase mobile doesn't support n1ql).

I could just call a rest web service done with .NET or maybe JAVA but so is it needed to add couchbase mobile to the app?

This is the query of C# couchbase mobile documentation:

```
    var document = database.CreateDocument();
var properties = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"type", "list"},
        {"title", "title"},
        {"created_at", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString ("o")},
        {"owner", "profile:" + userId},
        {"members", new List<string>()}
    };
var rev = document.PutProperties(properties);
Debug.Assert(rev != null);
```

how i Call it?

This is a query in Server documentation (the previous was in mobile):

```
var doc = new Document<dynamic>{ Id = "document_id", Content = new {Some="value"} };
var result = bucket.Insert(doc);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Document));
```

why they are different?

This is the function to connect the server to phonegap:

```
var DB_NAME = 'todo';

function initRESTClient(url) {
  var client = new SwaggerClient({
    spec: window.spec,
    usePromise: true,
  })
    .then(function (client) {
      client.setHost(url);
      if (device.platform == 'android') {
        var encodedCredentials = "Basic " + window.btoa(url.split('/')[1].split('@')[0]);
        client.clientAuthorizations.add("auth", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization('Authorization', encodedCredentials, 'header'));
      }
      client.server.get_all_dbs()
        .then(function (res) {
          var dbs = res.obj;
          if (dbs.indexOf(DB_NAME) == -1) {
            return client.database.put_db({db: DB_NAME});
          }
          return client.database.get_db({db: DB_NAME});
        })
        .then(function (res) {
          return client.document.post({db: DB_NAME, body: {title: 'Couchbase Mobile', sdk: 'PhoneGap'}});
        })
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log('Document ID :: ' + res.obj.id);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });

}
```

sorry if I'm a bit confused but I need some high level clarify to get started coding.

Comment: You could also look at https://pouchdb.com/ with the Cordova SQLite adapter for your client.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level: you need Couchbase mobile on the device and Couchbase Server on server (cloud or on premise). To push/pull data between mobile and server you need the Couchbase Sync Gateway running (cloud or on premise). More information is available over at the [Couchbase Mobile Portal for Developers](https://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/).

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your question as to why the .Net version of mobile and server queries are different-

- The Mobile version calls into Couchbase Lite which is the embedded NoSQL database for mobile client platforms. The database is embedded in your mobile/desktop client and it syncs periodically with the Couchbase Server in the cloud via the sync gateway. So you would typically implement this in your Windows mobile app. You can also implement this in your desktop client application.
- The server version - In this case, you would use the .Net SDK that queries against the Couchbase Server. You would implement this in your .Net web service app in your backend. You can implement your backend web service in any supported language including Java.

If you are considering Phonegap, you may want to refer to this [tutorial](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/installation/phonegap/index.html). This integrates with Couchbase Lite using a swagger client- there isn't a native JS API hence the swagger based client. The Couchbase Lite syncs with the Couchbase Server via the Sync Gateway.